# R: changing value of a cell depending on two conditions

Tags: r, dataframe

I would like to increase the value of a cell in a dataframe by 1 if two cells in other columns meet certain conditions. How do I do that?

This is how I do it for one condition:

```
`+`(data.frame[which(data.frame$col1 == some.value),]$col2 , 1)
```

I hoped that

```
`+`(data.frame[which(data.frame$col1 == some.value && data.frame$col3 == some.other.value),]$col2 , 1)
```

would work, but it doesn't.

Any ideas for an elegant solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First create some data to play with:

```
set.seed(1)
L = c("A", "B", "C")
dd = data.frame(x = sample(L, 10, TRUE), y = sample(L, 10, TRUE), z = 0)
```

So `dd` is a data frame with three columns:

```
R> head(dd)
  x y z
1 A A 0
2 B A 0
3 B C 0
4 C B 0
5 A C 0
6 C B 0
```

In the example below, if column `x` equals `A` and `y` equals `C` we should increase `z` by one:

```
dd$z = dd$z + (dd$x == "A" &  dd$y== "C")
```

The key part is:

```
(dd$x == "A" &  dd$y== "C")
```

which is a logical comparison and returns `TRUE` (1) or `FALSE` (0).